# Tkinter update a variable in a label

Tags: python, variables, tkinter

Can anyone help resolve this issue or point me in the right direction?

I am using Python 3.9.7

My goal is to create a python program that displays a timedelta between two variables using Tkinter, I want this variable to update each second as it counts down.

I have created the TK window, with my header text and timedif label appearing inside, however while my program runs the timedif label does not update. Timedif label only displays the timedelta when the program was executed.

I defined a function countdown_update intending to use the .after method to update the countdown every 1000ms, then included a print statement to visually see that the function was called. I can see the print statement in the terminal, my label does not update. I am unsure how to resolve this.

'''

```
from tkinter import * 
from datetime import datetime


#datetime.date = Year, Month, Day
#datetime.time = hour, minute, second
#datetime.datetime = Y,M,D,H,M,S,MS

#Declaration of variables
future_day = datetime(2022, 1, 7, 17, 0, 0, 555555)
today = datetime.today()
timediff = future_day - today

#Creating the TK Window
window = Tk()

# setting geometery of the window
window.geometry("500x300")

#Using title() to display a message in the dialogue box of the message in the title bar
window.title("Time until future day")

#adding a label to the window
Header = Label(window, background="black", text="Time Remaining", bg="purple", 
fg="black", font="none 24 bold")
Header.config(anchor=CENTER)
Header.pack(pady=20, ipadx=10, ipady=10)

#adding the timer to the window
timedif_label = Label(window, text=timediff, bg="black", fg="purple", font="none 28 
bold")
timedif_label.config(anchor=CENTER)
timedif_label.pack(pady=20,padx=20)

def countdown_update():
    timedif_label.after(1000, countdown_update)
    print("update finished")


#execute Tkinter
countdown_update()
window.mainloop()
```

'''

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You will need to place the `print` statement before `.after` to see the results

Comment: A string passed to the `text=` option of a Label is *fixed* - the Label isn't going to magically update itself, just because the code that generated the text would now produce a different result.  You have the right framework in place for updating the Label, in the form of your `countdown_update()` function that's being repeatedly called via `.after()` - you just need to recalculate `timediff`, and explicitly set the Label's `text` option to the new value, from within that function.

Answer (score 0):

Altering tkinter texts is not done by referencing a "normal" variable. Tkinter provides it´s own version of variables for this situation.

So to have changing text you would use StringVar(). In your case I recommend altering your timediff var like this:

```
timediff = tk.StringVar(str(future_day - today))
```

Altering your Label like this (mind the fact that "text" is now "textvariable"):

```
timedif_label = Label(window, textvariable=timediff, bg="black", fg="purple", font="none 28 
bold")
```

And finally altering your countdown_update like this:

```
def countdown_update():
    timediff.set(str(new_time)) #insert calculations here
    timedif_label.after(1000, countdown_update)   
    print("update finished")
```

So you set the tkinter StringVar and this should then alter the text displayed in your label

For further details you can checkout this:
https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python-tkinter/how-to-change-the-tkinter-label-text/